# A free and trusted CD Burner

Tags: gratis, windows-7

I need a CD burner that is free and doesn't contain malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/):

- Full-featured CD/DVD burning tools
- Free and open source
- Does not contain viruses or bundled adware ([Scan report](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/332704763605252ef9e88d2a8ce6d076719f0acb307db231069483ae5ca407ff/analysis/))

To be even safer, you can get the portable zip version from their [download page](http://infrarecorder.org/?page_id=5) which runs without an installer

Comment: That's the top open source result on http://alternativeto.net/tag/dvd-burning/ .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Free ISO Burner](http://www.freeisoburner.com/):

- Free
- Portable
- Microsoft Windows XP/2003/Vista/Windows 7/Windows 8
- No crapware
- Can directly burn your ISO and CD/DVD image file to CD-R,CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD+R, DVD+RW,HD DVD and Blu-ray Disc, no need mount any "virtual drives" which emulate physical CDs or DVDs, it write any data directly.
- Straightforward to use:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### [CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/)

Pro

- Free
- Create data, video or audio discs
- Save data compilations to a file, so you can later burn the same files to another CD/DVD
- Burn ISO files
- Verify burned data
- Copy CDs/DVDs to another CD/DVD or to your hard drive as a ISO file
- Delete a CD-/DVD-RW

Cons:

- **WARNING:** The default installer contains OpenCandy adware! Be sure to click on *More download options* on the [download page](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/download) and select the OpenCandy-free version.

Comment: No OpenCandy-free version as for today.

Comment: I have downloaded the portable version. It seems to be working OK. I don't know if it installed OpenCandy-free.

Answer (score 0):

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) is your 'suit all' solution.

- CD / DVD / HD DVD / Blu-ray
- Read/write disk images, folders, files
- [Write audio CDs as well](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/5555-how-to-write-an-audio-cd-from-music-files-using-imgburn/)
- Free
- Crapware can be opted-out during install
- FAQ, support forum

Not *very* actively maintained (last version is July 2013), but there doesn't seem to be much to maintain any more.

Comment: ImgBurn includes OpenCandy adware as part of the installer.

Comment: ImgBurn only makes data discs. I tested it with both a mp4 and mp3 and created two images to burn later, and it literally just copied the file into an ISO image, without converting it to a playable format for CD players or DVD players.

Comment: @Chloe 1) The OP did not request that and 2) You **can** [burn audio CD files with ImgBurn](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/5555-how-to-write-an-audio-cd-from-music-files-using-imgburn/)